# JProgressBar.stringPainted(true); is not working

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jprogressbar

This is a part of my java code, in this code I have written that when I click the button the value of `JProgressBar` should becomes `0` and `stringPainted()` returns `true`, but `"string painted"` is not visible when I click the button, please help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class R implements ActionListener {
    static int y;
    CustomProgressBar b = new CustomProgressBar();

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        new R();
    }

    public R() throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        f.add(b);
        f.add(btn);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomProgressBar extends JProgressBar {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean isStringToBePainted = false;

        public CustomProgressBar() {
            super(JProgressBar.VERTICAL,0,100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (isStringToBePainted) {
                Dimension size = CustomProgressBar.this.getSize();
                if (CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete() < 0.9) {
                    R.y = (int) (size.height - size.height * CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete());
                }
                String text = getString();
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(text, 0, R.y);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setStringPainted(boolean b) {
            isStringToBePainted = b;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        b.setValue(0);
        b.setStringPainted(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to call the `super.setStringPainted(b)`:

```
public void setStringPainted(boolean b) {
    super.setStringPainted(b);
    isStringToBePainted = b;
}
```

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but you might want to look into overriding ProgressBarUI, instead of the component.  Take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicProgressBarUI.html

Comment: could you explain more if you can?

Comment: why when I run it, it just show to %0 vertically and horiztionally

Comment: You are right, but I need only horizontal string not vertical, so what should I do???

Comment: I'm think that super.paintComponent(g); should be last code line inside paintComponent, otherise String isn't paintied

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `JProgressBar` `setStringPainted` method in your overriden method:

```java
public class TestGame implements ActionListener
{

  static int y;
  CustomProgressBar progressBar = new CustomProgressBar();

  public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception
  {
    new TestGame();
  }

  public TestGame() throws Exception
  {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    btn.addActionListener(this);
    f.add(progressBar);
    f.add(btn);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  class CustomProgressBar extends JProgressBar
  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean isStringToBePainted = false;

    public CustomProgressBar()
    {
      super(JProgressBar.VERTICAL, 0, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (isStringToBePainted)
      {
        Dimension size = this.getSize();
        if (this.getPercentComplete() < 0.9)
          TestGame.y = (int) (size.height - size.height * this.getPercentComplete());
        String text = getString();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString(text, 0, TestGame.y);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void setStringPainted(boolean b)
    {
      super.setStringPainted(b);
      isStringToBePainted = b;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: why when I run it, it just show to %0 vertically and horizontally ?

Comment: What are you expecting exactly?
You may need also wether to accept the answer or at least upvote it, since your primary question was about why it was not visible :)

Comment: You are right, but I need only horizontal string not vertical, so what should I do???

Comment: You are drawing the string representation by yourself `g.drawString(text, 0, TestGame.y);` in (0,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the [`paintAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paintAll(java.awt.Graphics)) method after setting the new `isStringToBePainted`'s value. As an advice, make the progressbar wider so you can appreciate the whole percentage label. I added a simple threading routine to watch your custom component at work, here are some pictures of it:

[image: The custom progressbar at 25% of progress]
[image: The custom progressbar at 50% of progress]
[image: The custom progressbar at 84% of progress]

The following code contains the details of the modifications made under comments tagged as `#NEW`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class R implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    static int y;
    CustomProgressBar b = new CustomProgressBar();

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
        new R();
    }

    public R() throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        btn.addActionListener(this);

        // #NEW: Make the progress bar a little bit wider
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 250));

        f.add(b);
        f.add(btn);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CustomProgressBar extends JProgressBar {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean isStringToBePainted = false;

        public CustomProgressBar() {
            super(JProgressBar.VERTICAL, 0, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (isStringToBePainted) {
                Dimension size = CustomProgressBar.this.getSize();
                if (CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete() < 0.9) {
                    R.y = (int) (size.height - size.height * CustomProgressBar.this.getPercentComplete());
                }
                String text = getString();
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(text, 0, R.y);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setStringPainted(boolean b) {
            isStringToBePainted = b;

            // #NEW: This updates the progressbar after clicking the button, thus fixing your problem
            paintAll(getGraphics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        b.setValue(0);
        b.setStringPainted(true);

        // #NEW: A simple thread that creates a visual of your component working 
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    // #NEW: This is the threading routine, it only changes the progressbar value from 0 to 100 every 10th of a second  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (b.getPercentComplete() < 1.0) { 
            b.setValue(b.getValue() + 1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```